# Proving that a sequence converges if $|a_n - a_{n+1}| < Mr^n$ for some $M > 0$ and $r \in (0,1).$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, cauchy-sequences

Let $\{a_n\}_n$ be a sequence. Suppose that there exist $M \gt 0$ and $r \in (0, 1)$ such that $|a_n - a_{n+1}| \lt Mr^n$ for all $ n \in \Bbb N.$ Prove that $\{a_n\}_n$ converges. I'm not really sure where to go about with this problem. I feel like the easiest way would be to prove that the sequence is Cauchy, but I'm not entirely sure. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: The answer I've added is based on a very similar question I've also asked here some time ago. I've only adapted it to use you notation. You may still want to take a look at the original [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3051454/proof-verification-x-n-is-a-sequence-such-that-x-n1-x-n-le-c-alp).

Comment: Possible duplicate of the link from roman’s comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may start by considering the following set of inequalities:
$$
\begin{align}
|x_{n+1} - x_n| &< Mr^n\\
|x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}| &< Mr^{n+1}\\
|x_{n+3} - x_{n+2}| &< Mr^{n+2}\\
&\cdots \\
|x_{n+p+1} - x_{n+p}| &< Mr^{n+p}
\end{align}
$$

Sum up the inequalities to obtain:
$$
|x_{n+1} - x_n| + |x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}| + \cdots + |x_{n+p+1} - x_{n+p}| < M\sum_{k=0}^pr^{n+k}
$$

By geometric sum:
$$
M\sum_{k=0}^pr^{n+k} = M\frac{r^n(1-r^{p+1})}{1-r} \le M\frac{r^n}{1-r}
$$

You can now choose some $\epsilon > 0$ and $N \in \Bbb N$ such that:
$$
M\frac{r^N}{1-r} < \epsilon \tag1
$$

Define:
$$
r = \frac{1}{1+q}, q\in\Bbb R_{>0}
$$

Thus:
$$
M\frac{r^N}{1-r} = M\frac{1}{(1-r)(1+q)^N} < \epsilon
$$

Or:
$$
N > \log_{1+q}\frac{M}{(1-r)\epsilon} \implies M\frac{r^N}{1-r} < \epsilon
$$

Now going back to the sum of absolute values and using triangular inequality one may obtain:
$$
|x_{n+1} - x_n + x_{n+2} - x_{n+1} + \cdots + x_{n+p+1} - x_{n+p}| \le |x_{n+1} - x_n| + |x_{n+2} - x_{n+1}| + \cdots + |x_{n+p+1} - x_{n+p}|
$$

Note the telescoping nature and you get:
$$
|x_{n+1} - x_{n+p+1}| < M\frac{r^n}{1-r} < \epsilon
$$

Now for all $n$ such that:
$$
n > N > \log_{1+q}\frac{M}{(1-r)\epsilon}
$$

the inequality $(1)$ holds, which shows that the sequence satisfies Cauchy's criteria hence convergent.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $m > n$,
$$|a_n - a_m|\le M(r^n + r^{n+1} +\cdots + r^{m-1})$$
(sum of a geometric progression $=\cdots$ ?)

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_{n+1}-a_n| \le \sum_{n=1}^\infty Mr^n = \frac{Mr}{1-r} < +\infty$$
Absolute convergence of a series implies convergence so
$$a_1 + \sum_{n=1}^\infty(a_{n+1} - a_n) = a_1 + \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=1}^{N-1}(a_{n+1} - a_n) = a_1 + \lim_{N\to\infty} (a_N - a_1) =  \lim_{N\to\infty} a_N$$
also exists.